# Problem signing PDF documents with iText 5.5.5

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to sign PDF documents with the library **iText 5.5.5**.

I have two certificates to sign documents, with one certificate all works perfect and you have a valid signed document. But the problem is with the second certificate, because you can sign the document but if I open the document with Adobe Reader the signature is invalid.

I'm using the same code for both certificates but I don't know why doesn´t works with one certificate. Here is the code that I use to sign the documents with **iText 5.5.5**

```
String pkcs11Config = "name=NAME" + "\n" + "library=PATH";
ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
ks.load(null, password);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfInput);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfOutputTemp);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

...

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass);
ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(key, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null);
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, crlList, null, tsc, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

I also attach two signed documents, one signed with the certificate that has no problems and the other with the certificate that invalidates the signature.

[Invalid Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YjSTpd2cJRtWG1mVYoziXbpZn7p2W7y6/view?usp=sharing)

[Valid Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mB_c5bYMEHekELE5QOEOEdyA2uJJ6tbz/view?usp=sharing)

I appreciate the help you can give me.Thank you

Comment: The problem is that the signed hash of the authenticated attributes is incorrect. I'm not sure yet what the cause is. Probably some certificate or revocation data added to those attributes is not properly DER encoded.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the answer, I'll check that. The most interesting thing is that it is the same code for both certificates, but only with one certificate works

Comment: As mentioned above, I think the problem may be caused by some improper encoding of the embedded certificate or revocation information, so in case of a certificate and revocation information which are properly encoded, everything works just fine. But I'm not sure that that really is the issue. Have you tried signing without embedding revocation information?

Comment: That being said, which exact BouncyCastle version do you use?

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the help. I removed the CRL's files from the signed document and the problem was solved, but we need the CRL's for the document to be LTV Enabled. I'm using these BouncyCastle's jars: bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar and bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar

Comment: Apparently there is an issue in those CRLs. Can you share them? (The embedded version may have been changed.) Furthermore, have goy checked whether OCSP responses can be retrieved? Using OCSP responses instead of CRLs would substantially reduce the signature size...

Comment: @mkl Of course, I can share the CRL's files. Here is the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15L60nMn1kEWz69WdA0AmPyVfcxDnD61c?usp=sharing . About the OCSP responses, I've never tried that.